# Dynamic load of object file to execute

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic, linker, loader

I was wondering what are the steps to load an object file (generated from a single source file by the the msvc compiler), load it in memory of my program already running (in a buffer for example) and then run the code inside it.

The use case is that I have a large program which take a minute to load and wanted to do real time modifications from source code. Like just load the object file, fix some addresses in this object file, use the -hotpatch function to intercept call in my already running process and redirect to my object file.

Seems to me that I should just resolve the import table of the object file to point to my already loaded programs and intercept the call of the functions which have been modified.

Am I missing something ? I would like to ask before trying it to not waste time on something that may be impossible !

Thanks !

Comment: My understanding is that an object file is an intermediate representation and not necessarily executable.  The object file may have unresolved symbols in it, which are resolved by a linker.  Are you confusing object files with static or dynamic libraries?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use dynamic libraries.  The operating system can load these into your program on demand or at start up.    The libraries can contain executable code and they generally have no unresolved external references.

Comment: The fact is that I want to resolve thoses references to addresses in my program already loaded. I don't want to relink the entire executable. And I don't want to use LoadLibrary functions.

Comment: Definitely should possible, quick googling shows [this](https://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/) example for Windows dlls.

Comment: Yeah except I want to load a .obj file not a .dll. So maybe there are some differences that I don't know about ?

Comment: Your executable doesn't contain symbolic names anymore; they are gone at linker stage. You won't be able to satisfy unresolved symbolic references from that .obj file.

Comment: Yeah I'm planning to get those symbols by using the pdb generated by the linker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the direct question (about loading and executing an obj file): this essentially amounts to re-writing a linker. Which is all but impossible.

As for (what I can figure out of) your intended usage: dynamically loading and executing an obj file wouldn't get you any closer to intercepting calls in your already running process. What you want is probably ***hooking***. There are a lot (no, seriously, *a lot*) of ways to do so. [Detours](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours?fid=1528778&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=76#xx0xx) is the more-or-less official way to achieve this, here's a [presentation](https://github.com/ionescu007/HookingNirvana/blob/master/Esoteric%20Hooks.pdf) of a few ways from the exotic side of the spectrum.

Comment: For the hook it seems pretty easy, never tried it, but it seems to just write a jmp in the old functions to your new function. I have some code named InterceptAPI which seems to do the trick. But again never tested it so I hope it works :D

Comment: It is that easy only if you don't intend to call the original function from your patch (or from elsewhere). If you do, you should probably read a bit more on the topic

Comment: I've seen some techniques called trampoline but i don't intend to use those because I want to just replaced the old functions by the updated code.